# Laravel 5.8 result query in where

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Good morning all

sorry for my bad english

I would like to transform this request to eloquent laravel

take into account that the minimum and maximum values ​​are dynamic

I tested a lot of solutions but there I am stuck.

I am not stopped at my request, if you have something more elegant I am taker.

```
select 
count(pa1.adherent_id) as numb
from polices_assurance as pa1
where 
(select SUM(pa1.montant_capital_assure) from polices_assurance as pa2 where pa2.adherent_id=pa1.adherent_id) >= 1 AND
(select SUM(pa1.montant_capital_assure) from polices_assurance as pa2 where pa2.adherent_id=pa1.adherent_id) <= 90000
```

my last test

```
$police = \App\Models\PoliceAssurance::where((DB::raw('select SUM(polices_assurance.montant_capital_assure) from polices_assurance as pa2 where pa2.adherent_id=polices_assurance.adherent_id')),'>=', $category->valeur_mini)
                                     ->where((DB::raw('select SUM(polices_assurance.montant_capital_assure) from polices_assurance as pa2 where pa2.adherent_id=polices_assurance.adherent_id')),'>=', $category->valeur_max)
                                     ->count('adherent_id');
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: your sql is wrong, what do u really want from the `PoliceAssurance`

Comment: Thank you for your answer I managed differently.

My request was good, it returned what I wanted

describe what I wanted would be complicated, the request should give you the answers

Have a good day